# Same accuracy while running cross validation on different features of a dataset in python

Tags: python-3.x, svm, cross-validation

I am doing a 10 fold cross validation on 6 features of a csv file. the first 3 features' accuracy are 82,76 and 80 respectively. but running CV on the rest 3 features returns exactly the same value as the one for second feature (76). I have set different value for random state during each run but it did not change anything. here is my code:

```
from sklearn.model_selection import KFold

kfold=KFold(n_splits=10, shuffle=True, random_state=0)

rbf_svc=SVC(kernel='rbf')

linear_scores = cross_val_score(rbf_svc, X, y, cv=kfold)

print(linear_scores)

print('Mean Absolute Error %2f' %(1 * linear_scores.mean()))
```

Answer (score 0):

First what is the size of the X and y? if the dataset is extremely large having more folds is good! So try making the kfold to 5. SVC kernel is fixed to rbf. So try to do a grid search with different kernel and different parameters.